# Leave temporarily an if loop inside a while loop until next function call

Tags: if-statement, while-loop

I have a small question that may require a longer a long question... Let's say there's a function which looks like this:

```
type function( type parameter1, type parameter2...etc) {
    // bla bla bla
    while(condition1){
        // blablabla again
        if(condition2){
            // stuff1 happens
            exit(1)
        }
        // stuff2 happens
    }
}
```

My function (simplified) looks like this.
Let's say that the `condition2` is that if local variables take specific values and after the stuff happening, I want to leave the function. However if my main looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    function(p1,p2,p3...); //condition not critical
    function(p4,p5,p6...); //condition is verified
    function(p7,p8,p9...); // this function won't be called since there's an exit that happened in the 2nd call
}
```

I want to know how to leave the function but not the entire program.

TL;DR: I want to leave loop but to enter it the next time.

Comment: You can usually `break` out of a while loop or `return` from a function to discontinue execution, but without exiting the program entirely. If you add a specific language tag to your question we could give concrete examples. Some languages allow you to label a loop (e.g. "loop1") and then break out of that specific loop with `break loop1;` (in the case of nested loops, for example).

Comment: but does `break` work in an if loop?

Comment: I can only see `goto` for "leave loop but to enter it the next time".

Comment: Call "return" to return from a function, not "exit" and not "break".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "return" statement to return from a function before reaching the last statement in that function. "break" only breaks out of the current loop and "exit" terminates the program.